# Get AngularJS to talk to .NET Web API secured with Azure AD

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have two different web projects on Microsoft Azure.  One project is a .NET MVC web application and the other project is a .NET Web API.

Both projects are configured to use Azure AD.  The MVC web application is able to get a token and use it to make requests against the Web API.  Here's sample code from the MVC web app.

```
string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
result = authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(todoListResourceId, credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

// Make a call against the Web Api
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, webApiBaseAddress + "/api/list");
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

So this code works just fine.  However, what I need to do now is call the Web API directly from an AngularJS application.  When I try to do that, I get a 401 unauthorized error.

The way I am doing this is by adding a header to the HTTP GET request sent by AngularJS.  I'm setting "Bearer" to the result.AccessToken value that I am passing to the page from my MVC application (code above).

Obviously this doesn't work. I suppose now my question is what are my options? Is there an official or better way to do this?  Let's say I wanted to make calls to the Web API from standard JavaScript (lets forget the complexities of AngularJS). Is there a way to authenticate with Azure AD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the canonical way of obtaining a token for an in-browser JS application would be to use the OAuth2 implicit flow. Azure AD does not currently expose that flow, but stay tuned: we are working on enabling the scenario. No dates to share yet.

HTH!
V.

Answer (score 1):

The work I mentioned in the older answer finally hit the preview stage. Please take a look at http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/ - that should solve precisely the scenario you described. If you have feedback on the library please do let us know!
Thanks
V.

Comment: This looks really great! Any idea when it will hit first release version? We're looking forward to use it on one of production websites ASAP. I mean is it a matter of weeks or months from now?

Comment: Hi EpisodeX,it's hard to commit to a specific time at this point. If you send us more details about your scenario we can see if there's any solution we can suggest. You can reach me via http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/contact/ - thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick response! We decided to give it a try in current stage, and keep up with any breaking changes that may occur. The scenario is very simple in fact so I hope that following your blog post linked in the answer will be enough to get it to work. Then I hope I'll be able to give you some feedback on how it went.